# ?referer=www.clickfind.com.au duplicate title tag

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

recently google webmaster tools has shown that i have a duplicate title tag

```
 http://www.mydomain.com/root_folder/mypage.htm
 http://www.mydomain.com/root_folder/mypage.htm?referer=www.clickfind.com.au
```

I tried fixing the problem with a redirect rule using the following code

```
 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^referer=.*$
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.com$1? [R=301,L]
```

using this rule i get redirected to http://www.mydomain.comroot_folder/mypage.htm as you can see there is no / between com and root_folder where there should be... can anyone help me with that i need to edit in the following code to fix this issue

Comment: I believe the "title tag" refers to the `<title>` tag in the `<head>` of the page itself, not related to an URL.

Comment: Just add a slash before `$1`, like this `/$1`.

Comment: @faa adding /$1 doesnt work it stops redirecting when i do that

Comment: Here: `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.com/$1? [R=301,L]`

Comment: @faa   ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.com/$1? [R=301,L] this is what i meant it stops redirecting when i do that

Comment: I understand. But that's the way to insert a slash in this case. My comment is not intended to answer your question. However, it should be: `RewriteRule .* root_folder/mypage.htm/?  [R=301,L]` instead of your rewrite rule. If `mypage.htm` file exists, most probably will be a loop, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add "/$1" then " " then "?"..

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^referer=.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.com/$1 ? [R=301,L]
```